# Read the length of a file of images with JavaScript/AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to automate the image loading on a gallery page. Is there a way for JavaScript or AJAX to read the number of images in a folder on the same server?

(I do not know any JQuery, and I don't have time to learn it right now. So, please, no JQuery. I'll study it after this semester.)

I tried this: *(infinite loop warning!!)*

```
function loadImages() {


    for (var i = 0; true; i++) {
        try {
            var photo = document.createElement("img");
            photo.src = "images/image" + i + ".jpg";
            photo.width = 100;
            photo.height = 75;
            photo.alt = "image" + i;
            document.getElementById("galleryBox").appendChild(photo);
        } catch (error) {
            break;
        }


    }



}
```

...but it never causes an error, so it's an infinite loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Why should it cause an error?

Comment: You need some serverside processing to know how many files there are in a folder on the server. You could however loop through all the images and when the length of an image equals zero the file is not on the server.

Comment: Because stop condition is `true`.

Comment: you are assuming that image element won't get created if path doesn't exist and would break your loop....doesn't work that way, if browser can't locate image from http request, image tag still exists in output

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, after spending all day on it, I ended up doing this:

```
    var noError = true; // sets a togglable error 
    var imageWidth = 180; // literal that sets the thumbnail size

// The main loop to cycle through photos in the file
function imageLoop () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20 && noError; i++) 
        loadImages(i);
}

// Create the photo objects (and then toggle the stop condition)
function loadImages(number) {

    var photo = new Image();

    // If the image loads ok, then this finishes off the image element:
    photo.onload = function() {
        photo.width = imageWidth; // sets the rest of the img props
        photo.height = imageWidth * 3/4;
        photo.alt = "image" + number;
        photo.id = "image" + number + ".jpg";
        // this one send the img to the HTML:
        document.getElementById("galleryBox").appendChild(photo);
    }

    // This catches any source-not-found condition:
    photo.onerror = function() {
        noError = false; // toggles 'noError' if image fails to load
    }

    // This loads the image source to the object:
    photo.src = "finalimages/image" + number + ".jpg"; 
}
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but I understand how it all works. Thanks for all your help folks.

Comment: This will fail if you have a folder with more than 20 files.
Also, it will generate a 404 in every load of the folder. You can edit this every time a picture is added. A cleaner solution always involves server side code.

Answer (score 1):

`try/catch` will only help you to catch JavaScript errors. If the image you requested is missing from server, response with 404 code will be returned and `error` event triggered. So your function should look something like this:

```
function loadImages() {
    var error = false;

    function toggleError() {
        error = true;
    }

    while (!error) {
        var photo = document.createElement("img");
        photo.src = "images/image" + i + ".jpg";
        photo.width = 100;
        photo.height = 75;
        photo.alt = "image" + i;

        photo.addEventListener("error", toggleError);

        document.getElementById("galleryBox").appendChild(photo);
    }
}
```

---

In general, better approach would be to ask server for a list of files in an AJAX request. Assuming that your server returns JSON array of image sources:

```
function loadImages() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && status === 200) {
            var images = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            images.forEach(function (src, i) {
                var photo = document.createElement("img");
                photo.src = src;
                photo.width = 100;
                photo.height = 75;
                photo.alt = "image" + i;
                document.getElementById("galleryBox").appendChild(photo);
            });
        }
    }

    xhr.open("GET", "http://images.example.com", true);
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

Comment: So would this return a list of the images in the file?`  xhr.abort();
xhr.open("get", "????", true); 
xhr.send(null);
xhr.onreadystatechange = readerFunction;
`

Comment: If on a good day loading an image *(404 or not)* takes a few hundred milliseconds, this script will potentially fire off several hundred duff requests before the first error finally comes back...

Comment: ...er, what I'm trying to say is: What does the xhr.open statement look like that returns a list of files in the folder?

Comment: @Cyclopeus you will need to `JSON.parse()` the response, see my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is client-side, so there's no access to the file system. But using AJAX, you can actually pass the list from a server-side script, say PHP, to client-side JavaScript, say in JSON, for example.

Comment: I know how to get an XML file, and display it. But how do you just get an index of files with AJAX?

Comment: @Cyclopeus this is a completely different question, I believe. The answer will depend on a server-side language your are using.

Comment: @Cyclopeus in PHP use the `glob()` function

Comment: Sorry, you lost me at PHP. I'm kind of a noob still.

Comment: @Cyclopeus you can't read the file system (ie the content of a folder) using only JS, you need another technology that has access to the file system, like a server-side scripting language

Comment: Validate the answer if it suits you

Answer (score -1):

- Javascript runs on the browser. The list of files in the server is in the server. You need something running on the server that the browser can request information from and that would list the files.
- Your for loop has no end condition so you will just burn CPU